# Connecting to postgreSQL port on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, iptables, firewall, postgresql

For a project I am working on we are using an Ubuntu 14.04 server and just to be clear, I am a Linux noob who is just starting out using Linux. This project requires the use of PostgreSQL 9.3, which I have installed using this walkthrough [How to Install PostgreSQL and phpPgAdmin](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/ubuntu-postgresql-installation/). So far everything works just fine.

To open port 5432 (the default port for PostgreSQL) we followed this [Allow remote connections](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/postgres-allow-remote-access-tcp-connection.html). In short, we edited the pg_hba.conf with a wildcard for all connections:

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust
```

And allowed TCP/IP by editing postgresql.conf

```
listen_addresses='*'
```

Next we configured iptables just like in the example:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0/0 --sport 1024:65535 -d OUR_IP_ADDRESS  --dport 5432 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s OUR_IP_ADDRESS --sport 5432 -d 0/0 --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

If I run the command `nmap localhost` as root I get these ports:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
5432/tcp open  postgresql
```

If I run the command `nmap OUR_IP_ADDRESS` I get these ports:

```
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
80/tcp open  http
```

Running `ps axf | grep postgres` returns

```
8217 pts/0    S+     0:00                          \_ grep --color=auto postgres
 3824 ?        S      0:16 /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf
 3826 ?        Ss     0:00  \_ postgres: checkpointer process                                                                                              
 3827 ?        Ss     0:03  \_ postgres: writer process                                                                                                    
 3828 ?        Ss     0:03  \_ postgres: wal writer process                                                                                                
 3829 ?        Ss     0:12  \_ postgres: autovacuum launcher process                                                                                       
 3830 ?        Ss     0:16  \_ postgres: stats collector process
```

When it try to run `psql -h OUR_IP_ADDRESS -U postgres -d test1` I get this error:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "OUR_IP_ADDRESS" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

So I guess something is still blocking the port, or maybe I am doing something wrong, but I am not sure what it is. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
As requested the result of `sudo netstat -nap | grep 5432`

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1066/postgres   
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5432                :::*                    LISTEN      1066/postgres   
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10040    1066/postgres       /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

Comment: Could you please post the result of `sudo netstat -nap | grep 5432` on the server?

Comment: I edited the post to include the output

Comment: There must be something wrong with your configuration. PostgreSQL is only listening on localhost (`127.0.0.1:5432`and `::1:5432`). Did you remove the `#` in the line `listen_addresses = ` and reload/restart postgresql after changing the configuration?

Comment: Dear god, it is working! Rebooting did the trick. Thanks a bunch!